# Flutter: Cannot initialise UID inside CollectionReference,when UID passed from One screen to Another

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-widget

Goal: I want to pass the `uid` which i get from my `homescreen.dart` to my `enroll.dart` and access data inside the firestore collection using the passed `uid`

Here's how i pass data from  `homescreen.dart` to `enroll.dart`

```
Future navigate(String id, String name) async {
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: ((context) => enroll(
              uid: id,
              name: name,
            ))));
   }
```

Here's how i access the data in my `enroll.dart`

```
class enroll extends StatefulWidget {
 final String uid;
 final String name;
 enroll({Key? key, required this.uid, required this.name}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<enroll> createState() => _enrollState();
}

class _enrollState extends State<enroll> {


 final CollectionReference programs =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(widget.uid); //This how i access the data
  }
```

Prolem: When i try to do so,it shows `The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression`

I tried giving the text widget the same by `Text(widget.uid)` and it work fine.

Iam new to flutter,Any help is Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a value from widget ('uuid' here) before the method 'initState' of '_enrollState'.
You need to wait the widget to be initialized.

You could do

```
class _enrollState extends State<enroll> {
    late final CollectionReference programs;
    
     @override
     void initState(){
         super.initState();
         programs = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(widget.uid); 
     }

}
```